# Material-ui layout scrambled after production build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I have build a website based on node.js, material-ui and create-react-app.

When I do a development build using `yarn start` I get this result on localhost:

[image: Localhost display]

Then, after doing a production build using `yarn build`, I get this:

[image]

All the functionality works except for the layout.

Any ideas what might be the cause?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What would be the best way to post it?

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: I'm working in it now. There is one dependency which is on GitHub.I get this error: Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds: Could not fetch version for @https://github.com/ahs-mediatheken/bo-module-taxonomie.git: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/@https:/github.com/ahs-mediatheken/bo-module-taxonomie.git/package.json'

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ahs-mediatheken/bo-main/tree/master/

Comment: I imported the sandbox directly from GitHub but there's still a problem with a link to another repo. I'll try to solve it

Comment: Colin, do you have an idea how to fix this error? I've made the repo public

Comment: how did you check production build? did you deploy it somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `material-ui` is included two extra times by rollup, which breaks the app. If you take a closer look at what is built in `med-react-component` and `bo-module-taxonomie` you will notice that rollup includes material-ui in both builds. 
Since you are using `rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external`, you should make `material-ui` peer dependency in both `med-react-component` and `bo-module-taxonomie`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.0.0",
    ...
```

Comment: Thx Evgeny! This solved my problem! I thought that npm never installed things twice but was wrong on that. You made me reflect on the difference between dependencies and peer dependencies. Great!

Comment: Actually, it's not about npm but rollup, you import what already built.